# Import export users from SharePoint group to excel using rest

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, angularjs

I want to add/remove users from SharePoint group when excel file uploaded by admin person using rest odata or angular.

Can any one please help me in this requirement?

Comment: Please provide more information!
Does the excel file contains the data about the users that needs to be added/remove from SharePoint group?

Comment: Yes I have excel file in which contains users email ids and based on that i want to add users into group or remove it.

Comment: Yes I have excel file in which contains users email ids and based on that i want to add users into group or remove it.

Comment: Please refer to my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will have to read the data from excel (let's say by CSOM) and save it in the lists.

From the list, read the data using REST API and store it in variable.

Then pass the user name dynamically to

**Add user to group:**

```
    executor.executeAsync({
  url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web
    /sitegroups(7)/users
    ?@target='<host web url>'",
  method: "POST",
  body: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName':'i:0#.w|domain\\user' }",
  headers: {
    "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_UserCollectionRequestExamples)

**Remove user from group:**

```
    executor.executeAsync({
  url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/sitegroups(7)/users
    /removebyloginname(@v)?@v='i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cuser%40domain.onmicrosoft.com'
    &@target='<host web url>'",
  method: "POST",
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_UserCollectionRemoveByLoginName)